# Embe Data: How to update a record

Tags: rest, express, ember.js, ember-data

I've got an record of my model 'item' via

```
store.find('item', 412).then(function(item){
...
});
```

The model looks like that:

```
item :{
   title: "mySuperItem",
   price: "45",
   comments: [
       23423,
       656332
   ]
}
```

However, what I want is to change the comments IDs in the founded record (want to add a new one).

So I thought it would be fine to do something like that:

```
...
.then(function(item){
    item.comments.push(234234);
    item.save().then(...); 
});
```

Unfortunately it's not working as expected. Ember throws curious exceptions!
Since I'm writing my Backend with the REST-API on my own (nodes.js/express.js) ember-data will send a simple OPTIONS-Call to the backend with the following headers:

```
Host: localhost:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type,x-access-token
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

My backend will return a answer which contains that header: `Allow:"GET,HEAD,PUT"` so it seems like my backend answered *"Hey its okay to send PUT-Calls to that address".* But ember prompts me to use CORS, but its not working since the method cannot be found in the CORS-Header *'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'*.

How could that be? Maybe I misunderstand something

### Edit for addition

As @torazaburo mentioned correctly, the model for Item has of course a hasMany-relation to "comments"-model. However here is the model for Item:

```
title: DS.attr('String'),
price: DS.attr('Number'),
comments: DS.hasMany('comment')
```

Also its now more clear that the problem is with the **save()**-Part. Its throws an unexpected "cross-origin" error as described above.

Any Help?

Comment: Please show the model for `item`. Is `comments` a `hasMany`? In that case, use `this.get('comments').addObject` to add to it rather than `this.comments.push`.

Comment: thanks @torazaburo. I added the model in my question. But as descriped above the main problem is with the save() methods which ends in cross-origin-problems. Can you help with that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header also. For example:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```